# MS Access Subform not adding row to table when blank

Tags: sql, ms-access-2016

quick question.

I have a small access db that has 3 tables for memo generation. On the main form you input all of your memo information such as what you purchased, from who, how many, etc. The main ID on the table (and all related tables) is purchase_id.

I created a subform on the main form which is just linked to another table and handles some easy yes/no questions such as "was the purchase over x amount", etc.

However, unless the user clicks into one of the text boxes on the subform, a new row will not generate in the table (even though in the subform I can see the ID linked).

Is there any way to make it so even if a user doesn't click into the subform a row generates in the table with all of the defaults I selected?

Thank you,

Comment: Yes. You can use any of these events (choose the one most appropriate for UI and need) - ON LOAD, ON OPEN, FORM CURRENT

Comment: Hi Doug,

Thank you for your response. So I would basically have to add the code for making a new row? I wouldn't want it to happen every time though. It's just if a user bypasses that subform because they don't need to select any options, I want the blank row still created. But if the user does decide to pick all the dropdowns on the subform, then per usual I'd like the row to be added.

Comment: you just need to decide what the appropriate event for this would be. Analyze your events in the properties section of the two forms and make a decision on whats appropriate